# Impossible to log out from OpenSuSE's KDE menu

Tags: kde, configuration, opensuse

I'm running OpenSuSE 12.1 with the KDE desktop on a test machine. The "logout" menu entry in the KDE menu does not seem to do anything. I am not aware of changing any KDE settings that might be relevant.

How can I find out the cause of this behaviour, and how can I remedy it?

Comment: try running kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This did, however, not change the situation.

Comment: i have a hard time imagining what you are actually talking about. can you include a screen shot, or describe a bit more?

Comment: It's simple: Clicking on the "logout" menu entry does not do anything except dismiss the launcher. There are no processes started, no log entries, nothing. I am both asking for ways how to diagnose this (I imagine there might be a way to make KDE's event handlers write more verbose info to the logs or something similar) and how to remedy the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [bug](http://lists.kde.org/?l=kwin&m=125400578301771) KDE knows about and seems to be quite common. It seems that it could be caused by KDE trying to play the "logoff" sound byte and hanging there.

The only solution I could find was to disable the audio (through the configuration menu) and try again.

Comment: Interesting... I'm on a server without configured sound system, so I'll check if thtat's related.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong when I initially tested this, but testing again today, disabling the sound system solved the issue! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed @jstarek, and that's for remembering this question.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem after update to OpenSuSE 12.1 . The cause of this problem was a slight change to the shutdown / reboot commands.

Look at the file `/usr/share/kde4/config/kdm/kdmrc` . Find `[Shutdown]` section, comment any `HaltCmd =` or `RebootCmd =` . This properties could contain old syntax for shutdown/reboot commands.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but those values were already commented out in my kdmrc. Also, setting them to valid values manually did not change anything.